# how can I connect an SVG image to a select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Ok, I have a problem, maybe an easy problem, I'm a newbie.

I have a *SVG image* that is acctualy a map (a region map), divided in sectors (that  are the cities). All is right, the *SVG* works perfectly. Also, I have a simple *drop-down list* (into *HTML*).

This is what I want:

when someone select an option (a city) in the menu, the selector (the region) appears selected. And, when someone select the selector (the region) the option in the menu (the city) appears selected.

I have attach images.

THANK YOU SO MUCH.

UPDATE:

drop-down menu HTML code:

```html
<label for="sel1">Seleziona Area:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
<option>1 - Udine Centro</option>
<option>2 - Rizzi / S. Domenico / Cormor / S. Rocco</option>
<option>3 - Laipacco / San Gottardo</option>
<option>4 - Udine sud</option>
<option>5 - Cussignacco</option>
<option>6 - S. Paolo / S. Osvaldo</option>
<option>7 - Chiavris / Paderno</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code for SVG image:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('g.chiavris').click(function() {
        $('g.chiavris').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    
    $("g.region").hover(function() {

        //mouse over
        $(this).find('.map-image').css('fill', '#8B8B8B');
     $(this).find('.map-title').css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {

        //mouse out
        $(this).find('.map-image').css('fill', '#ccc');
        $(this).find('.map-title').css('display', 'none');

    });

 $('.region').click(function(event) {

  var regions = $('.region');
  console.log(regions);

  for(var i=0; i<regions.length; i++){
   console.log('tutti messi normali '+ i);
   $(regions[i]).find('.map-image').css('fill', '#ccc');
         $(regions[i]).find('.map-title').css('display', 'none');
   $(regions[i]).bind('mouseenter mouseleave');

  }

  //DOPO
        $(this).find('.map-image').css('fill', '#FF7409');
        $(this).find('.map-title').css('display', 'block');
  
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        
    });


});
```

UPDATE 2:

OK, thanks all, I have upgrade your code like that:

```js
// per selezionare i "polygon" che influisce sul select
    $(".map-image").on('click', function(evt) {
        // Get the id of the region we clicked on
        var regionId = evt.target.id;
        // Update the dropdown
        $('#sel1 option').removeAttr('selected')
            .filter('[value=' + regionId + ']')
            .attr('selected', true);
        // Highlight the relevant region
        setRegion(regionId);
    });

    // Per selezionare dal select e avere il colore nella mappa
    $("#sel1").change(function(evt){
      //console.log($(this).val());
      var name_region = ($(this).val());
      var regions = $(document).find('#'+ name_region).get(0);
      //console.log(regions);
      $(regions).css('fill', '#FF7409');
    });

  

    /*function onRectClick(evt)
    {
      // Get the id of the region we clicked on
      var regionId = evt.target.id;
      // Update the dropdown
      $("#sel1").val(regionId).change();
      // Highlight the relevant region
      setRegion(regionId);
    }*/

    function onSelectChange() {
        // Get selected class from dropdown
        var selectedRegion = $("#sel1").val();
        // Highlight the relevant region
        setRegion(selectedRegion);
    }

    function setRegion(regionId) {
        // Remove "selected" class from current region
        $("polygon.selected").removeClass("selected");
        // Add "selected" class to new region
        $('polygon#' + regionId).addClass("selected");

        // Note: for addClass() etc to work on SVGs, you need jQuery 3+
    }


    // Init map based on default select value
    onSelectChange();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: I have updated my post. You can check the codes. I can't attach the SVG code because it is too long for the post :(
If you need it, tell me how I can attach that. Thanks.
If you need more infos ask me, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is more complicated than it needs to be.  The hover stuff you can just leave up to CSS.

The clicking and select changing can just be handled with event handlers.

All you need to do is give each map region an `id` and assign a corresponding value to each `<option>` element.

Then just update the select, and change the class of the region based on whether you click or change the select field.

```js
$("rect").click(onRectClick);
$("#sel1").change(onSelectChange);


function onRectClick(evt)
{
  // Get the id of the region we clicked on
  var regionId = evt.target.id;
  // Update the dropdown
  $("#sel1").val(regionId);
  // Highlight the relevant region
  setRegion(regionId);
}

function onSelectChange()
{
  // Get selected class from dropdown
  var selectedRegion = $("#sel1").val();
  // Highlight the relevant region
  setRegion(selectedRegion);
}

function setRegion(regionId)
{
  // Remove "selected" class from current region
  $("rect.selected").removeClass("selected");
  // Add "selected" class to new region
  $('rect#'+regionId).addClass("selected");
  
  // Note: for addClass() etc to work on SVGs, you need jQuery 3+
}


// Init map based on default select value
onSelectChange();
```

```css
rect {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: #888;
}

rect.selected {
  fill: #ff7409;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <rect id="region1" x="50" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region2" x="150" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region3" x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region4" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region5" x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region6" x="50" y="200" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect id="region7" x="150" y="200" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>  

<div>

  <label for="sel1">Seleziona Area:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option value="region1">1 - Udine Centro</option>
    <option value="region2">2 - Rizzi / S. Domenico / Cormor / S. Rocco</option> 
    <option value="region3">3 - Laipacco / San Gottardo</option>
    <option value="region4">4 - Udine sud</option>
    <option value="region5">5 - Cussignacco</option>
    <option value="region6">6 - S. Paolo / S. Osvaldo</option>
    <option value="region7">7 - Chiavris / Paderno</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: I have posted an update, if you want, check it thanks.

Comment: What update? Your question has not changed since I posted this answer.

Comment: I have put an update about your code. All perfectly works. Just one thing... when I select the city on the menu the region remain selected (with orange color), it's ok, but when I pass "hover" with the mouse, the selection disapper (so the orange color is gone)

Comment: Thanks you very much for all

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Can you message me? I am trying to do something very similar with a map. The map is filled with <g> groups and I am getting an error on the line with 

unrecognized expression: rect#
$('rect#'+regionId).addClass("selected");

Comment: @user2025730 If you are using an actual map, you almost certainly won't want to user `'rect#'` it'll be `'g#'` or `'path#'` etc. Or try just using `$('#'+regionId)` instead.